# TrueType Fonts in various Environments

Tags: linux, truetype

Trying to utilize TTFs for image rendering. I didn't have any on the Linux box the application sits; I was at a loss and took a shot in the dark by SCPing the TTFs from my local machine to the server and pointing the application to them. I figured this wouldn't work since my machine is Windows, and box is Linux....but it was a shot in the dark. Alas, it didn't work. My question is: Are TTFs OS and OS Architecture specific?

Comment: It might be a silly question, but I'm new to the usage of TTFs....so...yeah :D

Answer (score 0):

No. They are plain data files, and data files are *not* OS specific (although their use may be).

The one single exception I can think of is that in the Bad Old Days, Apple's native file storage format on the Macintosh used two different disk objects: one for 'code' and one for 'data'. Without special software, only the 'code' parts could seen on other computers, leading to a swift exorcism of this storage format when Apple realized the rest of the world had problems reading their files. Still, it's far from unusual to read messages of confused people, finding that extracting an old Mac zip file can result in lots of zero-byte files.

As for your problem: since the problem does not lay in the font file *format* (there is no reason TTF "cannot work" on your system), it should be either the software you are using (does it actually support TTF fonts?) or - and I consider this more likely - you made an error transferring the files and you ended up with damaged fonts.

Comment: Yeah, I know it utilizes TTF fonts as i've opened SRs with the supplier and they explicitly said for linux environments they require TTFs....but they aren't able to supply, or tell us where to get the Fonts....so I just SCPed the ones from my machine to the server with WinSCP....